# jQuery if condition 1 or condition 2 is true than

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to alert "yes" if ether of the conditions in my if statement are true:

```
var a = 2;
var b = 1;
if (a = 1 or b = 1 ) {
    alert('yes');// should alert in this case
} else {
    alert('no');
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/90z7urvd/1/
What do I use for the if, if this is possible?

Comment: `=` is assignment. `==` and `===` are comparison.

Comment: Nick if you dont want this kind of situation in future, try using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nsjithin/90z7urvd/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a = 1` will set the value 1 to variable a. It is not doing a comparison. For comparison, you use `===` or `==`

`===` (Identity operator) is the correct way to compare if both the types are same.

```
if (a === 1 || b === 1 ) {
```

`===` operator won't do the type conversion before the comparison while `==` does the type conversion before the comparison.

For your or case, You may use `||` operator

```
var bootresul = someExpression || anotherExpression
```

Corrected code

```
var a = 2;
var b = 1;
if (a === 1 || b === 1 ) {
    alert('yes');
} else {
    alert('no');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assiging value rather then comparing

Try like this

```
if (a == 1 || b == 1)
```

To compare strictly use `===`

Like this

```
if (a === 1 || b === 1)
```

<kbd>**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/gv47s52x/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

you can do this

```
var a = 2;
var b = 1;
if ((a == 1) || (b == 1 )) {
    alert('yes');// should alert in this case
} else {
    alert('no');
}
```

the == is one of the relational operator for checking equality and || is a logical operator that is a notion of logical OR

Answer (score 1):

use this to compare just values

```
if (a == 1 || b == 1){

}
```

OR use this to compare values and type of variable

```
 if (a === 1 || b === 1){

 }
```

note : `==` will just check of values and `===` this will check value with type of variable

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = 2;
var b = 1;
if (a == 1 || b == 1 ) {
 alert('yes');// should alert in this case
} else {
alert('no');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you were doing assignment instead of comparison

Try using this:

```
if(a === 1 || b === 1){  
  alert('YES!') 
}else{
  alert('NO!') 
}
```

OR you can use ternary operator condition instead of if else

```
(a == 1 || b == 1) ? alert('YES!') : alert('NO!')
```